# Excel: How to check string if there are other answers aside from a given array of choices? (i.e. if there are "other" answers)

Tags: excel

I have this following table:

[image: Table]

These are answers to a multi-response question (i.e. survey questions where there is a "check all applicable" instruction)

Using the following formula, I can check whether cells A2 to A4, contain the answers in cells B1 to D1.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1; A2; 1));1;0)
```

This returns 1 if the string contains the answer, and 0 if it does not.

The problem I have is how to structure the code as to search the string and determine if it has other answers aside from the given array of choices (i.e. A, B, & C)

I am trying to transform my data so that I can process them in SPSS.

Comment: Have you actually checked your formula?  I don't see how it can possibly give you accurate results.  And is `other answer` any free form text?

Comment: I already have. The SEARCH function searches the string and returns the number where the searched string is found. If it has a value, ISNUMBER returns TRUE, which gives me an answer 1, through the IF function. and yes `other answer` is any free form text.

Comment: Copy the formula that you posted into your worksheet.  It is looking for the string `A,B` within the string `A`.  I suspect you just typed in the formula and didn't actually use what you have posted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Mind you that I still do not have a function for "Others"

Comment: First I need to understand how what you have posted is working.  Because if it really is, there is something about your setup that I do not understand.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld my mistake. it should have been `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1;A2;1));1;0)`. It works perfectly now.

Comment: OK, that makes sense now.  But if you replace your `B4` with `B, (other answer)` you will see that your formula will return a `1` for both `A` and `B`, since `SEARCH` is case-insensitive.  And even using `FIND`, there would still be an error if you had something like `B, (other Answer)` in B4

Comment: Is there a maximum number of answers?

Comment: Oh I see. But the options and answers are over simplified. Meaning, in reality, the answers in the array are quite lengthy, so excel can properly discriminate the options.

Comment: There is a maximum, if the respondent checked all the given options, and checked `others` and placed his own answer, the number of choices + his own answer will be the max

Comment: A more realistic example might be useful.  But one approach might be to count the number of answers in Column A; if you do your comparison to the known answers, and you have one left over, than you have an `other` answer.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the answers are less than 1000 characters each, and so long as there is a unique separator between the answers, (I assumed a comma as you showed in your example), then the following should work.  If you require that the comparison between the actual and potential answers be case-sensitive, you can use the `EXACT` function.

But it seems to me a different method of entering the answers onto the worksheet would be preferable.

In the formulas below, you will need to change the comma (where used as a separator between function arguments) to the semicolon you have in your locale.

First, define a named formula `Formulas --> Define Name`

```
seq_999  Refers To:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*999)
```

Then:

```
B2:  =SUMPRODUCT(N(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999))=B$1))
```

The formula splits A2 into an array, based on the comma separator, and then sees if any element of the array is equal to the contents of B1.  If it is, it will count the `1`.

Fill this across up to but not including the `Other` column; and fill down as far as needed.

**EDIT** check for column A being empty

In the `Other` column, we use this formula:

```
E2:  =IF($A2<>"",N((LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",","")))=SUM(B2:D2)),0)
```

We compare the number of answers that are matched in the first row, with the total number of answers in Column A to determine if there is an extra.  If there is, there must be an `other`.

[image]